# How to set up a simple pie chart using React in ChartJS on codesandbox

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, codesandbox

Following the [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) documentation and setting up a Pie chart on codesandbox gets everything working, except the options don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up `react-chartjs-2` with `import { Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";`, codesandbox will automatically save the latest stable release of `react-chartjs-2` and `chart.js` as dependencies. This unfortunately breaks things. You need to change the versions in this panel on the left hand side of your codesandbox panels.

[image]

I've made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/interactive-pie-8n26u?file=/src/App.js), which can be forked to keep all of the dependencies. It also demos a few options that can be adjusted on the chart.